# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'AAC' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, mongodb, jupyter-notebook

I'm new to my cs-340 course and need help. My error is "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'AAC' referenced before assignment". I just may have more errors than the first I received. Please help! All help is appreciated. Thank you

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

def load_all_items_from_database(AAC):
    print("Loading all items from database:")
    projects = AAC.read()
    at_least_one_item = False
    for p in projects:
        at_least_one_item = True
        tmp_project = Project.build_from_json(p)
        print("ID = {}".format(tmp_project._id))
    if not at_least_one_item:
        print("No items in the database")


def test_create(AAC, new_project):
    print("\n\nSaving new_project to database")
    AAC.create(new_project)
    print("new_project saved to database")
    print("Loading new_project from database")
    db_projects = AAC.read(project_id=new_project._id)
    for p in db_projects:
        project_from_db = Project.build_from_json(p)
        print("new_project = {}".format(project_from_db.get_as_json()))
        
           

def main():

    AAC = AAC()
    
    #display all items from DB
    load_all_items_from_database(AAC)

    #create new_project and read back from database
    new_project = Project.build_from_json({"title": "data"})
    test_create(animals, new_project)

    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: In your own words, where you have written `AAC = AAC()`, how are you expecting it to know what to do?

Comment: I know I need to initiate the variable but I don't know how seeing I'm new to this and have been researching in which that many examples show different ways including using "global". I really need help. To note as well AAC is the database.

Comment: Well, what does it say in the assignment handout? For example, what does the name "AAC" mean? Why are you calling it that, instead of something else? When you say it "is the database", what does that mean? On the other hand: where you wrote `from pymongo import MongoClient`, in your own words, why? What do you think that does? Is there a specific part of your code that you think relies on that line? What part?

Answer (score 1):

you should define or import AAC. that is very simple logic: first define, then use!
please give us a short explanation of what AAC is